# How do I get list of pods which are consuming high CPU and Memory in Grafana dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, monitoring, azure-aks

There are multiple namespaces in the AKS cluster and all the pods in those namespaces have CPU/Memory requests and limits set. But I need to get the top 5/10 pods which are consuming high CPU and Memory amongst all the namespaces based on the limits set for each of them. And display this list in Grafana.